Snippet to echo a selected variable
I have in my bash code:
time=$(echo $timestamps | xargs)

I would like to have after a snippet is done:
time=$(echo $timestamps | xargs)
echo "[var time] = $time"

I tried to put my own snippet like below:
"Echo's to console": {
    "name": "echo selected word in BASH",
    "prefix": "echo",
    "body": [
        "${TM_CURRENT_LINE}",
        "echo \"[var ${1:${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}}] = \\$${1:${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}}\"",
        "$2"            
    ],
    "description": "echo selected word in BASH"
}

My result:
time=$(echo $timestamps | xargs)
echo "[var time] = $time"
=$(echo $timestamps | xargs)

I will be grateful if you improve my snippet and additionally explain why my code is not works correctly.

I looks like you are selecting the word time of time=$(echo $timestamps | xargs) first and then triggering a keybinding assigned to your snippet.
Since you have selected something, the entire snippet will replace just that selection.  So time gets replaced by ${TM_CURRENT_LINE}, then a newline, then the second line of your snippet, then a newline.
So the rest of that first line (that you didn't select) just gets pushed down to the end.  Which is why you see =$(echo $timestamps | xargs) at the end.  It isn't part of your snippet, it gets pushed down when your snippet is inserted in front of it for the word time.
Note that ${TM_CURRENT_LINE} might be working differently than you expect.  In your case it will result in the selection (time) to be replaced by
time=$(echo $timestamps | xargs)

which is actually what you want on the first line but still leaves the unselected part of that line unchanged and pushed down by the rest of the snippet.  ${TM_CURRENT_LINE} does not select that line, instead that entire line gets inserted where the selection was.

How to fix your snippet : you want to get rid of that trailing
=$(echo $timestamps | xargs)

I find that difficult to do if you are selecting just part of the line. It is much easier to just manually select the entire line - then that entire line will be replaced by your snippet.  But then you have to find a way to get just the time part from the entire line.  That is pretty easy in your case of
time=$(echo $timestamps | xargs)

just use the regex part of a snippet transform to grab everything before the first =.  This will do that:
${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/^([^=]*)(.*)/$1/}  // remember you are now selecting the entire line

so if you do this:
${1:${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/^([^=]*)(.*)/$1/}}

$1 will be assigned to the result of the transform which is just time.  Likewise
${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/^([^=]*)(.*)/$2/}  would be everything, in capture group `$2`, after `time`.

Now you can recreate the current line with
"${1:${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/^([^=]*)(.*)/$1/}}${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/^([^=]*)(.*)/$2/}"

that just outputs time=$(echo $timestamps | xargs) where that line was (selected) - but you now have a tabstop $1 that contains the word time which you can use in the next part of your snippet:
"echo \"[var $1] = \\$$1\""  // outputs echo "[var time] = $time"

because the $1's are replaced by the word time.  So you end up with this snippet:
"Echo's to console": {   // use this as the `name` property in a keybinding
    // "name": "echo selected word in BASH",  // doesn't belong here
    "prefix": "echo",
    "body": [
        "${1:${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/^([^=]*)(.*)/$1/}}${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/^([^=]*)(.*)/$2/}",
        "echo \"[var $1] = \\$$1\"",
        "$2"            
    ],
    "description": "echo selected word in BASH"
}

and this keybinding:
{
  "key": "alt+k",                 // whatever keybinding you want 
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "args": {
    "name": "Echo's to console"
  }
}

Result:


Actually there is a much more straightforward way to do this (and with a simple snippet) by using the runCommands command in a keybinding to do multiple steps, but then you don't learn why your snippet was doing what it was.  Here is that way to do it (in a keybinding):
{
  "key": "alt+k",              // whatever keybinding you want 
  "command": "runCommands",
  "args": {
    "commands": [
      "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",   // select 'time' only
      "editor.action.insertLineAfter",
      {
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "args": {
          "snippet": "echo \"[var $CLIPBOARD] = \\$$CLIPBOARD\"\n$1",
        }
      },
    ]
  }
}

Here you would select the word time only first and then trigger the keybinding and it does exactly what you want!

It is a very long time when I saw such an extensive and complete answer. Thank you @Mark for your effort. I have checked both solutions: they work well.
